# How to burn bootloader into arduino uno without using another arduino

Tags: arduino-uno, programming, bootloader

I need to bootload my Uno board but I do not have another Arduino at my disposal so how do I bootload without another Arduino board

Comment: with AVR programmer

Comment: Sorry, I am new to this will you mind explaining further or may provide a link to relevant video/document for the procedure @Juraj

Comment: perhaps you should explain why do you need to 'bootload'

Answer (score 2):

There are 3 main options how to write bootloader or program to AVR over ISP.

1. [dedicated AVR programmer](http://www.ladyada.net/learn/avr/programmers.html) or [Arduino ISP programmer](https://store.arduino.cc/arduino-isp)
2. other Arduino with Arduino as ISP sketch or similar
3. [parallel port of a computer](https://www.instructables.com/id/Simplest-AVR-Parallel-port-programmer/)

Answer (score 2):

The USBTinyISP programmer attaches to your computer's USB port and uses the 6-pin ICSP port on your Arduino to program it.  It can program both bootloaders and sketches.  It can be purchased for less than $10 from Amazon or Ebay.

[USBTinyISP programmer](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B075LJPF4L)